# How get USDT balance BEP-20? web3.eth.getBalance

Tags: binance-smart-chain, bep20

Good day! Can you please tell me how you can get the balance of the USDT address? I found a way to get BNB balance (https://docs.binance.org/smart-chain/developer/BEP20.html), but there is no example for USDT

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Token balance of an address is **not** a property of the address. It is stored in each of the token's contract. So you need to call the `balanceOf()` function of the token contract, passing it the holder address as a parameter.

For example the [BUSD](https://bscscan.com/token/0xe9e7cea3dedca5984780bafc599bd69add087d56) token:

```
const busdAddress = "0xe9e7CEA3DedcA5984780Bafc599bD69ADd087D56";
const holderAddress = "0x8894e0a0c962cb723c1976a4421c95949be2d4e3";

// just the `balanceOf()` is sufficient in this case
const abiJson = [
    {"constant":true,"inputs":[{"name":"who","type":"address"}],"name":"balanceOf","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"uint256"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},
];

const contract = new web3.eth.Contract(abiJson, busdAddress);
const balance = await contract.methods.balanceOf(holderAddress).call();
// note that this number includes the decimal places (in case of BUSD, that's 18 decimal places)
console.log(balance);
```

Comment: How can we get the balance of these proxy tokens?
Ex -https://bscscan.com/token/0xbf5140a22578168fd562dccf235e5d43a02ce9b1#readProxyContract

Comment: @AjoyKarmakar You can treat the proxy address as any other address. If the contract implementation is hidden under the proxy address, you can pass the proxy address to the `Contract` JS class. If you're interested in token balance of the proxy address, you set it as the `holderAddress` in the above snippet... As for the shared Uniswap proxy contract: If you want to know how much UNI tokens are owned by this (Uniswap) proxy contract, pass the proxy address to both places.

Comment: Tried 'you can pass the proxy address to the Contract JS class' but it's showing me a balance of 0.

Comment: const otherContract = await new web3.eth.Contract(
    abi,
    '0xba5fe23f8a3a24bed3236f05f2fcf35fd0bf0b5c'
  );

  const otherBalance = await otherContract.methods
    .balanceOf('0xa859D1f24F27B550bf4ba3B54D15d88D51Df5018')
    .call();
  console.log('otherBalance', otherBalance);

Comment: @AjoyKarmakar The result is correct. The USDC contract address doesn't own any USDC tokens. You can verify this by passing the `0xba5f...` address to the `balanceOf()` function on the [contract detail](https://bscscan.com/address/0xba5fe23f8a3a24bed3236f05f2fcf35fd0bf0b5c#readContract) page on BSCScan.

Comment: Basically you are saying right but how do I get the UNI balance of my account?

Comment: @AjoyKarmakar To get the UNI balance of your account, you pass the UNI proxy address to the `Contract` JS object, and your address to the `balanceOf()` function.

Answer (score 0):

Fetch USDT balance on BNB chain using BSC scan API

```
const axios = require('axios');

const bscApiKey = 'YOUR_BSCSCAN_API_KEY'; // Replace with your BSCScan API key
const targetAddress = 'TARGET_ADDRESS'; // Replace with the address you want to query

const usdtContractAddress = '0x337610d27c682E347C9cD60BD4b3b107C9d34dDd'; // USDT BEP-20 contract address on BSC
const bscScanApiUrl = `https://api.bscscan.com/api?module=account&action=tokenbalance&contractaddress=${usdtContractAddress}&address=${targetAddress}&tag=latest&apikey=${bscApiKey}`;

async function fetchUSDTBalance() {
  try {
    const response = await axios.get(bscScanApiUrl);
    const usdtBalance = response.data.result;
    console.log(`USDT Balance of ${targetAddress}: ${usdtBalance}`);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error:', error.message);
  }
}
```